# How to fix subplot size in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having some trouble plotting my data with matplotlib.
What I want is to plot multiple curves in six graphs which are arranged with 2 rows and 3 columns.
Everything is fine, but when the maximum value at the x-axis changes, the position of ticks changes
and this leads to the change of each subplot.
Is there any way to fix the size of each subplot?
I attached the part of my code and screenshot to show what actually happens.

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2, ax3), (ax4, ax5, ax6)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=3)

ax1.plot(x1, y1)
ax1.set_xlim(0, max(x1))
ax1.set_ylim(-0.5, 1.05)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(5))

ax2.plot(x2, y2)
ax2.set_xlim(0, max(x2))
ax2.set_ylim(-0.5, 1.05)
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(5))

ax3.plot(x3, y3)
ax3.set_xlim(0, max(x3))
ax3.set_ylim(-0.5, 1.05)
ax3.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(5))

ax4.plot(x4, y4)
ax4.set_xlim(0, max(x4))
ax4.set_ylim(-0.5, 1.05)
ax4.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(5))

ax5.plot(x5, y5)
ax5.set_xlim(0, max(x5))
ax5.set_ylim(-0.5, 1.05)
ax5.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(5))

ax6.plot(x6, y6)
ax6.set_xlim(0, max(x6))
ax6.set_ylim(-0.5, 1.05)
ax6.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(5))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of setting the maximum value of each graph, it is better to set the maximum value of each of the 6 x-axis to a fixed value. `ax?.set_xlim(0,2000)`

Comment: It would be nice... but there are more sets of data and the maximum values quite deviates from 2000, so I cannot set a fixed value for it.